# The eigenvalues of SPD matrices and the diagonal of $R$ (from the QR decomposition).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $M$ be a real $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and let $M=QR$ be the QR decomposition of $M$ ($Q$ is orthogonal and $R$ is upper triangular).

Is there a connection between the smallest eigenvalue of $M$ and the smallest eigenvalue of $R$?

In other words, are there constants $c,C$ (that might depend on $\lVert{M}\rVert$ and $n$) such that

$$c\sigma_n=c\lVert{M^{-1}}\rVert^{-1}_2\le \min_{1\le i\le n} |R_{i,i}| \le C\lVert{M^{-1}}\rVert^{-1}_2=C\sigma_n$$

Where $\sigma_n$ the smallest singular value/eigenvalue of $M$.

---

What I have figured out so far: $c=1$ works. If $\sigma_n=0$, then equality is true for any $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider the case where $M$ and $R$ are invertible since you have taken care of the other case.

Note that since $M^TM = R^TR$, the singular values of $R$ are the singular values/eigenvalues of $M$.

With that, we can see that no $C$ will be large enough.  For instance, consider the matrix
$$
R = \pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&1}.
$$
We find that the smallest singular of $R$ is given by
$$
\sigma_2^2 = \frac 12 (t^2 + 2 - t\sqrt{t^2 + 4}),
$$
so that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \sigma_2(R(t)) = 0$.  However, the smallest eigenvalue of $R$ (for any $t$) will be $1$.

Comment: The inequality that I mentioned only involves the smallest singular value.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood.  In that case, no $C$ is going to work.  I'll edit accordingly

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: @aziiri Every upper triangular $R$ (and every matrix $R$, for that matter) satisfies $M = QR$ for **some** SPD matrix $M$, so I don't see what you mean with the "countable number of values".  What exactly do you mean by $\|R\|$ in this case?  What is $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: Please ignore the previous comment, I am wondering if $C$ depends on $\sigma_1(R)$ (the biggest singular value) and whether fixing it would change the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, fixing $\sigma_1(R)$ would change the conclusion.  Note that $\lambda \leq \sigma_1(R)$, which means that it would suffice to take $C = \frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_n}$.

Comment: Can $C$ depend only on $\sigma_1$?

Comment: @aziiri not without further constraints.  Note that the example $R(t)$ that I give can be scaled so that $\sigma_1(R)$ is any desired value, but even with scaling the ratio of $|\lambda|$ to $\sigma_n$ remains the same.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.